# Storing user input in an array and saved on sharedpreferences

Tags: android, arrays, sharedpreferences

How can I go about storing user input and making a list using sharedpreferences

I figured you would need an array of some sort, just not sure how to go about it.
Here is some code I have.

MainActivity class:

```
 public void SavePreferences (View view){
    SharedPreferences prefer = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = prefer.edit();
    EditText editLName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLName);
    EditText editFName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFName);

    List<String> user = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> pass = new ArrayList<String>();

    userList.add(editFName.getText().toString());
    passList.add(editLName.getText().toString());

    for(int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++){
        prefEditor.putString("user_" + i, user.get(i));
        prefEditor.putString("pass_" + i, pass.get(i));
    }
    prefEditor.commit();

}
```

Made some changes to the MainActivity just so I can illustrate better what I'm trying to achieve. I think one of the issues here is that this would overwrite any existing users, and I still don't have a means of retrieving the list.

SavedPreferences Class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.savedview);
    SharedPreferences prefer = getSharedPreferences("Prefs",MODE_PRIVATE);


    TextView txtMulti = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMulti);


    txtMulti.setText(list);
}
```

Comment: Forget about `Preferences` make one `Static Arraylist` and append values on it and fetch it.

Comment: What you want to do actually? Is the user input is permanent?

Comment: Yeah that is the idea

Comment: workaround(quite literally too): you can make an `ArrayList` as per your need and save the `toString()` value in `SharedPreferences`, retrieve `String`, `for-each` back to the `list`